# How do I add a directory to $PATH for a user?

Tags: settings

I'm using the Adafruit Webide and logged into my rpi as webide@raspberrypi

I'm trying to add the directory of my node installation to the $PATH but I can't do it.

Every time I reboot and try env I get nothing.

I've tried adding the directory to /etc/profile and /home/webide/.bash_profile but neither work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
PATH=NODE_JS_HOME=/usr/share/adafruit/webide/repositories/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi                                                                            
PATH=$PATH:$NODE_JS_HOME/bin                                                                                                                                      
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PATH=NODE_JS_HOME=/usr/share/adafruit/webide/repositories/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi
```

Here you went wrong. It will not work with **multiple** equals signs. Please try

```
NODE_JS_HOME=/usr/share/adafruit/webide/repositories/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi  
PATH=$PATH:$NODE_JS_HOME
```

---

**EDIT:**

If the new PATH is exported via **.bash_profile**, the changes are not effective immediately. Try

```
source .bash_profile
```

Comment: Now I have this file: /home/webide/.bash_profile containing NODE_JS_HOME=/usr/share/adafruit/webide/repositories/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi                                                                                    
PATH=$PATH:$NODE_JS_HOME/bin                                                                                                                                      
export PATH Still doesn't work!

Comment: I reinstalled node in a more sensible location to get around the problem.

I feel dirty for not getting to the bottom of this one but life is short.....